# VueJS - parent object is affected by changes in deep copy of this object in child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity, vue-props

Lets start with explaining the structure. I have the page dedicated to a specific company and a component `Classification.vue` on this page which displays categories of labels and labels itself which are assigned to the current company. First of all I get all possible categories with axios get request, then I get all labels, which are assigned to the current company, and after all I map labels to respective categories. Here is the `Classification.vue`:

```js
import DoughnutChart from "@comp/Charts/DoughnutChart";
import ModalDialog from '@comp/ModalDialog/ModalDialog';
const EditForm = () => import('./EditForm');

export default {
    components: {
        DoughnutChart, ModalDialog, EditForm
    },
    props: ['companyData'],
    async created() {
        const companyLabels = await this.$axios.get('/companies/' + this.companyData.id + '/labels');
        const allLabelsCategories = await this.$axios.get('/labels/categories');
        allLabelsCategories.data.map(cat => {
            this.$set(this.labelsCategories, cat.labelCategoryId, {...cat});
            this.$set(this.labelsCategories[cat.labelCategoryId], 'chosenLabels', []);
        });
        companyLabels.data.map(l => {
            this.labelsCategories[l.label.labelCategory.labelCategoryId].chosenLabels.push({...l.label, percentage: l.percentage})
        });
    },
    computed: {
        portfolioChartData() {
            let portfolios = [];
            // 35 id stands for 'Portfolio' labels category
            if (this.labelsCategories[35] !== undefined && this.labelsCategories[35].chosenLabels !== undefined) {
                this.labelsCategories[35].chosenLabels.map(label => {
                    portfolios.push({label: label.name, value: label.percentage});
                });
            }
            return portfolios;
        },
        portfolioLabels() {
            let portfolios = [];
            // 35 id stands for Portfolio labels category
            if (this.labelsCategories[35] !== undefined && this.labelsCategories[35].chosenLabels !== undefined) {
                return this.labelsCategories[35].chosenLabels;
            }
            return portfolios;
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            labelsCategories: {}
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good, I get the object `labelsCategories` where keys are ids of categories and values are categories objects which now also have `chosenLabels` key, which we set up in `created()`. And as you can see I use computed properties, they are necessary for a chart of 'Portfolio' category. And I used $set method in created() exactly for the purpose of triggering reactivity of `labelsCategories` object so computed properties can respectively react to this.
Now I have a new component inside `Classification.vue` - `EditForm.vue`, which is dynamically imported. In this component I do pretty much the same thing, but now I need to get every possible label for every category, not just assigned. So I pass there prop like this:

```js
<modal-dialog :is-visible="isFormActive" @hideModal="isFormActive = false">
       <EditForm v-if="isFormActive" ref="editForm" :labels-categories-prop="{...labelsCategories}" />
</modal-dialog>
```

And `EditForm` component looks like this:

```js
export default {
    name: "EditForm",
    props: {
        labelsCategoriesProp: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
            default: () => ({})
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.labelsCategories = Object.assign({}, this.labelsCategoriesProp);
    },
    async mounted() {
        let labels = await this.$axios.get('/labels/list');
        labels.data.map(label => {
            if (this.labelsCategories[label.labelCategoryId].labels === undefined) {
                this.$set(this.labelsCategories[label.labelCategoryId], 'labels', []);
            }
            this.labelsCategories[label.labelCategoryId].labels.push({...label});
        });
    },
    data() {
        return {
            labelsCategories: {}
        }
    }
}
```

And now the problem. Whenever I open modal window with the `EditFrom` component my computed properties from `Calssification.vue` are triggered and chart is animating and changing the data. Why? Quite a good question, after digging a bit I noticed, that in `EditForm` component I also use $set, and if I will add with $set some dummy value, for example:

```js
this.$set(this.labelsCategories[label.labelCategoryId], 'chosenLabels', ['dummy']);
```

it will overwrite the labelsCategories value in the parent component (`Classification.vue`)
How is it even possible? As you can see I tried to pass prop as {...labelsCategories} and even did `this.labelsCategorie = Object.assign({}, this.labelsCategoriesProp);` but my parent object is still affected by changes in child. I compared prop and labelsCategories objects in the EditForm component by `===` and by 'Object.is()' and they are not the same, so I am completely confused. Any help is highly appreciated.
Btw, I can solve this issue by passing prop as `:labels-categories-prop="JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(labelsCategories))"` but it seems like a hack to me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was digging deeper in this issue and learned, that neither `{...labelsCategories}` nor `Object.assign({}, this.labelsCategoriesProp)` don't create a deep copy of an object only the shallow one. So, I suppose that was the cause of the problem. In this article I learned about shallow and deep copies of objects: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-deep-copy-objects-and-arrays-in-javascript-7c911359b089

So, I can leave my hacky way using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(labelsCategories))` or I can use a library such as lodash:

```js
_.cloneDeep(labelsCategories)
```

But according to the article I also can create a custom method. And this one option is quite suitable for me. I already had a vue mixin for processing objects, so I just added deepCopy() function there:

```js
deepCopy(obj) {
    let outObject, value, key;

    if (typeof obj !== "object" || obj === null) {
        return obj; // Return the value if obj is not an object
    }

    // Create an array or object to hold the values
    outObject = Array.isArray(obj) ? [] : {};

    for (key in obj) {
        value = obj[key];
        // Recursively (deep) copy for nested objects, including arrays
        outObject[key] = this.deepCopy(value);
    }

    return outObject;
},
```